# MySQL workbench not starting Error while loading "Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec"

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

I am facing issue while starting MySQL workbench
Error:

> > Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec, sys.path = >>['/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries', '/Library/Frameworks
> > /Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
> > /Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7
> > /lib-dynload']
> > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

OS:

> > macOS Catalina
> > version:
> > 10.15.7

which python

> > /usr/bin/python

brew info python

> > python@3.9: stable 3.9.1 (bottled)

vi ~/.bash_profile

> > alias python='python3'

import sys
sys.path

> > ['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
> > /python39.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
> > /3.9/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
> > /3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar
> > /protobuf/3.14.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

MySQL workbench was installed via downloading the dmg file from dev.mysql.com

Updated Python version to python3 using brew

How to resolve the issue

Comment: Probably related to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102284.

Comment: Issue resolved,unistalled mysql workbench version 8.0.23 and installed mysql workbench 8.0.22

Comment: @amith well done!